# Using Microsoft Search Server 2008 with asp.net/vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, search

I'm installing Microsoft Search Server 2008 express with a view to indexing some content for an intranet application.

Having not used Search Server before, i am looking at ways of my asp.net app (.net 3.5) querying the search server.

I'm just starting to look into [Search Community Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/sctsc) to see if it is relevant to what i want to achieve.  But was wondering if you guys can point me in the right direction (code, articles, etc).

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few google searches, came across this website which fits the bill pretty well.

http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Ted-Nyberg/Dates/2009/1/Using-EPiServer-and-Microsoft-Search-Server-2008/

Describes using the Search Server web service, which is quite a clean way to do it.

Comment: http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Ted-Nyberg/Dates/2009/1/Using-EPiServer-and-Microsoft-Search-Server-2008/ not found, XML error. Alternatives? samples ?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides developer APIs. The assemblies are part of the Search Server 2008 SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931107.aspx