# ASP.NET search website

Tags: asp.net, search-server

I have a issue designing am asp.net site. 
The problem is that I want to have a search component that searches article titles.
Also I want to catch closely words. 
Since there are tens of thousands of articles I cannot run SQL directly.

Can you give me a hint... or some good articles how to design a search component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use MS Search Server Express Edition to index your contents and then use MS Search Server API to query and display results? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581322/using-microsoft-search-server-2008-with-asp-net-vb-net) has some information about it if you are interested.

Comment: I wanted to go on the direction of indexing all words from article titles in separate tables ....

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use Google to index and search your website for you using their custom search service:

http://www.google.com/cse/

The downside with this service is you get a bit less control over exactly what gets indexed on your pages, and can only search on terms directly visible on the pages,  but the upside of course is you don't have to do much to get up and running.